# same problem with treeview

Tags: c#, .net

```
private CTreeNode GetParentNode(CTreeNode node)
    {
      CTreeNode cTreeNode;
      TreeNode[] nodes = this.treeview.Nodes.Find(node.Name, true);
      if (nodes[0].Parent == null)
        cTreeNode = nodes[0] as CTreeNode;
      else
      {
        cTreeNode = nodes[0].Parent as CTreeNode;
        CTreeNode.Nodes.Clear();
        cTreeNode.Nodes.Add(nodes[0] as CTreeNode);
        this.GetParentNode(cTreeNode);
      }

      return cTreeNode;
    }
```

this is the function which is designed to get the node like 
(if a contains b and c and b contains d and e,

```
a--b--d
    --e 
 --c
```

if d is passed to this function a node will returns which is a but a has b and b has d
`a--b--d`).

but when i pass d to this function only b node is returned.

when i debugged and see, the line switches between return function and this.GetParentNode(customTreeNode);

i dono why, i think i m missing some basics

can i know why..

Comment: Why are you cloning? It makes no sense...

Comment: if i add it directly it is not adding. now check the code.. again the problem exists

Comment: Should you not return from `this.GetParentNode(cTreeNode);` ?  I dont understand what the problem is. Please clarify.

Comment: -1: Can you Clarify your question? it is difficult to know what you are asking, also, can you please give the question a meaningful title? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to build a node path

```
CTreeNode[] nodes = this.treeview.Nodes.Find(node.Name, true);
List<CTreeNode> nodepath = new List<CTreeNode>();
GetNodePath(nodes[0], nodepath);

private void GetNodePath(CTreeNode node, List<CTreeNode> nodepath) {
    nodepath.Add(node);
    if (node.Parent != null) {
        GetNodePath(node.Parent, nodepath);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Corrected code

Comment: Correct or not, the OP may get confused when the compiler errs as `return` is present.